# How to make div autoresize based on other div heigth?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 blocks: one above other. Top block could change it's size after some events. I can't be sure that I know each event.

I want top block to fill as much space as it need. The block below should fill all space below top block and show scroll if this space is not enough.

Is it possible to do it without js? If not, is there any reliable event like "onBlockResized"?

```
<div id="div1">
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
JSFiddle is awesome<br />
<a href='#' class='toogler'>toogler</a>
<div class='toogle'>
    JSFiddle is awesome<br />
    JSFiddle is awesome<br />
    JSFiddle is awesome<br />
    JSFiddle is awesome<br />
</div>
```

```
<div id="div2">
    I want div2 to fill free area bellow div1 and show sroll inside div2 if there isn't enought space. It should reflect any changes of height of div1. Is it possible to make it without js?<br />
    I want div2 to fill free area bellow div1 and show sroll inside div2 if there isn't enought space. It should reflect any changes of height of div1. Is it possible to make it without js?<br />
    I want div2 to fill free area bellow div1 and show sroll inside div2 if there isn't enought space. It should reflect any changes of height of div1. Is it possible to make it without js?<br />
    I want div2 to fill free area bellow div1 and show sroll inside div2 if there isn't enought space. It should reflect any changes of height of div1. Is it possible to make it without js?<br />
    I want div2 to fill free area bellow div1 and show sroll inside div2 if there isn't enought space. It should reflect any changes of height of div1. Is it possible to make it without js?<br />
    I want div2 to fill free area bellow div1 and show sroll inside div2 if there isn't enought space. It should reflect any changes of height of div1. Is it possible to make it without js?<br />
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndukruo4/)

Comment: there is an event you can use : <div onresize="myScript">

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Can you explain a bit more? Cause in the fiddle, I see no free area. And for having scroll inside div2 you can always set a max-height to it.

Comment: @DipaliVasani it's not working

Comment: @Jason div1 can change it's size. I want div2 to fill all area bellow div1. In this case max-height of div2 depend on height of div1.